# How to check to most recent element hovered with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this program where you can create draggable `<div></div>'s`, the div can then be dragged to a `<td></td>` in a table and when you hover over the `<td></td>` a button is displayed when you click the buttton everything in the hovered over `<td></td>` should be removed.

I tried to check for the `<td></td>` that's being hovered and delete everything inside with this function, but it didn't:

```
    function dump() {
     var hover = $("td").hover;
      $( hover ).remove();
    }
$( "button" ).on( "click", dump );
```

Is it even possible to check for the div that's being hovered? If not what can I do to remove the content in the `<td></td>`?

**here in more detail is what my code aims to do:**

user inputs text -> users input is outputted in a draggable div -> user can drag output into a `<td></td>`-> user can then click a button (which is displayed on hover) to delete the content in the `<td></td>`

Here is my full code:

```js
function addElement () { 
  
  var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  
  // create a new div element and give it a unique id
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.id = 'temp'

  // and give it some content
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text); 
  
  // add the text node to the newly created div
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent);  

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 

  $(function() {
    
    var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

    $(div).draggable();
    $("#temp").draggable();

    $(td).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) { 
          $( this )
          .addClass("div")
            .html( text );
              $("div").draggable();

          $( "#temp" ).remove();
      }
    });
  });


  document.getElementById("input").value = " ";



$(function () {
    $("td").dblclick(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var currentEle = $(this);
        var value = $(this).html();
        updateVal(currentEle, value);
    });
});

function updateVal(currentEle, value) {
    $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" type="text" value="' + text + '" />');
    $(".thVal").focus();
    $(".thVal").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
        }
    });

    $(document).click(function () {
            $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
    });
}

}



    var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

  $( "td" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<button>Click</button>" ) );

    function dump() {
      /*"function to remove content in only this <td></td> that has been hovered over*/
    }
$( "button" ).on( "click", dump );


  }, function() {
    $( this ).find( "button" ).last().remove();
  }
);
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

.blank {

}

.div3 {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 20px ;
  background-color: white;
  width: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}


.div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

td{
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 20px ;
  width: 200px;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>Input text:</h1>
    <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="input">
    <button onclick="addElement()" >input</button> 

    <p>Drag your outputs to the div:</p>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td height="50" width=100></td>
    <td height="50" width=100></td>
    <td height="50" width=100></td>
  </tr>
</table>


     <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just assign the target for dump to the button that you create on hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple "dump-function" that works as you expect/describe

```js
function addElement () { 
  
  var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  
  // create a new div element and give it a unique id
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.id = 'temp'

  // and give it some content
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text); 
  
  // add the text node to the newly created div
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent);  

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 

  $(function() {
    
    var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

    $(div).draggable();
    $("#temp").draggable();

    $(td).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) { 
          $( this )
          .addClass("div")
            .html( text );
              $("div").draggable();

          $( "#temp" ).remove();
      }
    });
  });


  document.getElementById("input").value = " ";



$(function () {
    $("td").dblclick(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var currentEle = $(this);
        var value = $(this).html();
        updateVal(currentEle, value);
    });
});

function updateVal(currentEle, value) {
    $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" type="text" value="' + text + '" />');
    $(".thVal").focus();
    $(".thVal").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
        }
    });

    $(document).click(function () {
            $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
    });
}

}



    var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

  $( "td" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<button>Click</button>" ) );

    function dump() {
      $(this).parent().html("").removeClass("div");
    }
$( "button" ).on( "click", dump );


  }, function() {
    $( this ).find( "button" ).last().remove();
  }
);
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

.blank {

}

.div3 {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 20px ;
  background-color: white;
  width: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}


.div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

td{
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 20px ;
  width: 200px;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>Input text:</h1>
    <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="input">
    <button onclick="addElement()" >input</button> 

    <p>Drag your outputs to the div:</p>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td height="50" width=100></td>
    <td height="50" width=100></td>
    <td height="50" width=100></td>
  </tr>
</table>


     <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

though it feels kinda odd to add the button on hover, personally I would add the button on drop with display:none and just show it with css on hover

Comment: Thank you! I also had to assign the appended button with an id because the button was interfering with the input button. I assigned the appended button an id, and it works I just wanted to know if the syntax was correct:    `$( "td" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<button>Delete</button>" ) ).attr('id', 'melement');`